# Jupyter lab on ubuntu does not start browser

Tags: ubuntu, python, parallels, anaconda

I'm using an Ubuntu VM in parallels (running on OSX M1 Processor).

Jupyter lab works fine on my base conda environment. When I launch it from an environment I created, nothing happens.